# Having trouble using LIKE %...%

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm trying to use the `LIKE %...%` what I have so far is this

```
SELECT * FROM stores WHERE 'name' LIKE '%$searchTerm%' AND price > 0
```

Unfortunately this returns the entire table instead of the specific term that is being searched. I also checked the value of the `$searchTerm` variable and it's working as intended.

Comment: please use [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) so we can see the entire issue including your table structure

Comment: I overlooked the single quotation, everything works now, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do not provide single quotes around your column name : if name is your column_name then try this:

```
 SELECT * FROM stores WHERE name LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' AND price > 0
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I overlooked those quotes haha.